# How to capture several text from a file and print it with specific format?

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file with the following content:

```
CLASS
1001
CATEGORY
11 12 13 15
16 17
CLASS
3101
CATEGORY
900 901 902 904 905 907
908 909
910 912 913
CLASS
8000
CATEGORY
400 401 402 403
```

and I like to reformat it using perl or awk to get the following result:

```
1001 11&12&13&15&16&17
3101 900&901&902&904&905&907&908&909&910&912&913
8000 400&401&402&403
```

Your help would be appreciated. (I used to do it with excel VBA), but this time I like to make it simple using perl or awk. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Its not my job, I only exercising. I used to do it with excel VBA and I like to learn perl/awk, sometimes it would be easier to learn by example and analyze it and this proven that perl/awk is simpler but powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -lne'
  BEGIN{ $/ ="CLASS"; $" ="&" }
  ($x, @F) = /\d+/g or next;
  print "$x @F"
' file
```

output

```
1001 11&12&13&15&16&17
3101 900&901&902&904&905&907&908&909&910&912&913
8000 400&401&402&403
```

Comment: Thanks! It is very simple :) This make me wanna learn perl so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` version

```
awk '/CLASS/ {c=1;f=0;if (NR>1) print a;next} c {a=$0 " ";c=0} /CATEGORY/ {f=1;c=0;next} f {gsub(/ /,"\\&",$0);a=a $0} END {print a}' file
1001 11&12&13&1516&17
3101 900&901&902&904&905&907908&909910&912&913
8000 400&401&402&403
```